# Jquery shows variable name instead of value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a ajax delete function, but the variable `qid` does not show it value in the url. It just shows its name.

The code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".delete_question").click(function(){
        var qid = 3;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/backend/questions/delete/"+qid,
            data: '',
            success: function(data){
                load_questions();
            }
        });
        return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!
    });
});
```

What my browser shows:

```
url: "http://localhost/cit/index.php/backend/questions/delete/"+qid,
```

Comment: That is correct, the + operator works as a concatenate when used with strings in javascript, so when that value is evaluated the url string will be concatenated with the value of the qid variable, resulting in something like "http://localhost/cit/index.php/backend/questions/delete/3"

Comment: Are you saying that you see `url: "http://localhost/cit/index.php/backend/questions/delete/"+qid,` in your code when you view the source, or that when the ajax request is executed, that `http://localhost/cit/index.php/backend/questions/delete/"+qid` is sent to the server?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "What my browser shows:"? Source code? Developer tools? Network tab?

Comment: @zeroflagL Source code shows qid, developer tools shows qid, network tab shows 3.

Comment: @9edge: if network tab shows 3, then what are you worrying about?

Comment: @zeroflagL I didn't notice that until now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems fine to me. You should actually make a request and see that its going to the right place.

Comment: I feel pretty stupid now. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

`qid` is a Javascript variable so should not be swapped out in the JavaScript code.

The URL it redirects to, will be `http://localhost/cit/index.php/backend/questions/delete/3`

If you want it to show as `http://localhost/cit/index.php/backend/questions/delete/3` in the JavaScript, you must make this PHP.

Like so:

```
$(function(){
    $(".delete_question").click(function(){
        <?php $qid = 3; ?>
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/backend/questions/delete/<?php echo $qid; ?>",
            data: '',
            success: function(data){
                load_questions();
            }
        });
        return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!
    });
});
```